# How to create a second socket for mysqld

Tags: mysql-5.0

I would like to create [second mysqld instance](https://serverfault.com/questions/609537/run-second-mysqld-instance-for-backup-restore).

How can I create a second socket file?

I tried copying `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` and create an empty file `mysqld2.sock` but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use mysqld_multi, which is part of a typical MySQL server install. On my Ubuntu server, it was located at /usr/bin/mysqld_multi.

[MySQL's Documentation on mysqld_multi](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqld-multi.html)

Here is a how to, I used to set up mysqld_multi: [MySQL Multi How to](http://share.ez.no/blogs/philippe-vincent-royol/mysql-multi-or-how-to-run-multiple-mysql-instance-on-the-same-server)

**Update, running a 2nd instance from the shell**

*Start another mysqld using a different, port, socket and data directory*

```
# make a new data directory
mkdir /var/lib/mysql2

# give ownership to mysql user
chown mysql:mysql -R /var/lib/mysql2

# install mysql database
mysql_install_db --user=mysql --datadir=/var/lib/mysql2/

# run 2nd daemon
/usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql2 
--user=mysql 
--log-error=/var/log/mysqld2.log 
--pid-file=/var/lib/mysql2/mysql2.pid 
--bind-address=127.0.0.1 --port=3307 
--socket=/var/lib/mysql2/mysql2.sock &
```

*Then connect to the 2nd instance with mysql*

```
mysql --port 3307 --socket=/var/lib/mysql2/mysql2.sock
```

Comment: Isn't there a shorter way to just start up a second instance? It will normally be running only for a few minutes to export some data.

Comment: But the [manuel](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-servers.html) said you can: "It is possible to use a different MySQL server binary per instance, or use the same binary for multiple instances". You just need to add some parameters and add a second socket file. I am only missing the socket.

Comment: I see what you mean, then you would execute the second mysqld daemon manually including port number, socket file, user to run as, etc from the shell. Something like /usr/bin/mysqld --user=mysql --port=3307 --socket=path, etc. I'm going to try that out locally

Comment: @PiTheNumber, okay, updated my answer with another solution